# how reduce fetch/XHR response time

Tags: ajax, rest-api

i using this code for ajax requset

front code:

```
function ajax_request() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'action': 'myFunction',
                    'data' : 'data'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    ...
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    ...
                }
            })
        })

    }
```

backend code :

```
function myFunction()
{
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            // do something
            wp_send_json(true);
        }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction');
```

for backend I added codes to functions.php file which have about 2000 lines of code

problem is average response time is about 4 5 second which actually long
when I clear those extra line of code and keep just code related to ajax the complete cycle of ajax process will be about 300 or 400 milliseconds ...
how I can reduce that time while keep that 2000 lines of code ?

Comment: what do your 2000 lines of code do? What is taking up that extra time when those 2000 lines are present? It's not possible to tell you how to make code faster without knowing what the code is and what it does.

Comment: @TomJNowell more of them are related to db

Comment: The only general purpose answer I can think of is implementing caching of your requests, if you can

Comment: cache request ? 
how

Comment: @hosseinkhosromanesh without seeing the code it's not possible to answer this, you should narrow your question down to specifics with concrete examples, this is incredibly broad and open ended right now. Remember this isn't a general discussion forum, you need a specific question that can be answered with hard facts